# Supply additional ssh options in config file

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

How can I supply additional options in .ssh/config?
I know that information like Host, Port, User etc. may be used in the ssh-configuration file to abbreviate ssh commands. I frequently create ssh-tunnels using the options "-Nf" to fork to the background. Is it possible to provide such options within the configuration file as well, and how?

Answer (score 3):

I often do the same thing with `LocalForward` directives.  I also use connection muxing with `ControlMaster`, `ControlPersist`, and `ControlPath` directives; if I want to have a connection that I use just for the tunnels, since my connections' muxers persist for 30 minutes, I can `ssh user@hostname.example.com logout` and have 30 minutes to open any tunnelled connections, and the tunnels will remain open until I've not used any of them *for* 30 minutes.

Here are the relevant bits of my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/mux/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
ControlPersist 30m

host shortname
    User username
    HostName remotehost.example.com
    LocalForward localhost:1234 192.168.6.76:1234
```